# Do people have multiple heads?

Tags: countability

I know every person has their own head.
-> Each person has a head above the neck.

I can see other people's headS in the crowd.
-> I can see lots of headS among the crowd.

I know people have their own headS.
-> Each person has more than a head ?

Comment: People is plural, so people have their own heads. This means that each individual person has his or her own head.

Comment: Seriously, do you need to ask this question?  Because when you understand a phrase you do so in context.  You are **not** a robot.  You don't have to just follow rules.  So when someone says "I know people have their own heads", please use your knowledge of human biology to guide your understanding.

Comment: Yes, you know each animal has only one head.

So, if you encounter only a simple sentence 'People have headS' ,
you can promptly imagine
the shape.

that aside, are those sentences below
correct ?

The space invaders surprised
people inhabiting the earth
 have only A  head.

They made A decision to protect pandas.

The people  have A big mountain
in the north of the town.

Comment: There are lots of duplicates of this, but I can't find any!

Comment: "Sarcasm is a defence mechanism", says psychology. Biology nods like hell..

Comment: @JamesK In other languages this might be a very startling sentence and indeed prompt the question of whether it's a typo. Hence when I read in Camus that "les gens essayaient leur front," I thought, "Do all those people share a single forehead?" (the inverse of this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence  "The aliens have heads" is ambiguous.  It could mean one head each, it could mean multiple heads each.

The sentence "The people have heads" is technically ambiguous but pragmatically understood because we know that each person has one head.

There are times when this ambiguity is problematic, but this is not one of them. You can avoid the ambiguity by using words like "each", numerals, or collective nouns

> Do the students have pencils?  (ambiguous)

> Does each student have a pencil? (not ambiguous)

> Does each student have five pencils/many pencils? (not ambiguous)

> Does each student have a pack of pencils? (not ambiguous)

Comment: Thank you. I can clearly understand the differences.

Comment: @Kumas If this answer tells you all you needed to know you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark.